# Python regex to extract substring including \n from multiple strings

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract a substring from a given string -

```
string0 = 'Daily wage of the worker0.1- \nNone'
string1 = 'Daily wage of the worker0.2- \nInvalid'
string3 = 'Daily wage of the worker0.3- \nValid'
```

There are 50 strings in the similar format. I want to extract `- \n` from each line. What is the correct regex expression?

I am trying `re.search(r'^- \\n$', re.DOTALL)`. What modifications do I need to make?

Comment: Remove `^`, `$` and `re.DOTALL`

Comment: I highly recommend googling for an "online regex tester" such as https://pythex.org/ I find them invaluable for writing and testing regex expressions before coding it out.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works. And @SherylHohman thank you for the suggestion, I will use them to test my expressions first

Answer (score 0):

You can match the very pattern you specified:

```
import re
s = ['Daily wage of the worker0.1- \nNone', 'Daily wage of the worker0.2- \nInvalid', 'Daily wage of the worker0.3- \nValid']
new_s = [re.findall('- \n', i)[0] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['- \n', '- \n', '- \n']
```